# Cordova BluetoothSerial plugin : discoverUnpaired method not working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to code a mobile crossplatform app that uses the Bluetooth hardware of the device to scan the area and display the list of bluetooth devices available for connection in the area.

So naturally I used google to find a way to do it and found and installed this plugin : [BluethoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) to use this method : [discoverUnpaired](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#discoverunpaired) which seemed to be the perfect tool to achieve what I wanted to do.

So using a bit of code they gave as an example :

```
bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired(function(devices) {
    devices.forEach(function(device) {
       console.log(device.id);
    })
}, failure);
```

I ended up with this :

```
function reshButt() {
alert('reshButt');
bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired(
    function(devices) {
        var currentNode;
        devices.forEach(
            function(device){
                currentNode = document.createElement('div');
                currentNode.id = device.id;
                document.getElementById(device.id).innerHTML = '<div id="'+device.name+'" onclick="bluetoothSerial.connect('+device.address+', alert("Connecting to '+device.name+'"), alert("Impossible to connect to '+device.name+'"));">'+device.name+'</div></br>';
                document.getElementById("devices_list").appendChild(currentNode);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

}

It's ugly I know.
But it doesn't work, I wanted to insert in the html code of the app the list of devices found in the area, and I wanted the user to be able to connect to connect to a device by clicking on it but everytime I try to run the code the variables *devices* and *device* are undefined.
It kind of doesn't surprise me as they seem to get out of nowhere but in the documentation of the plugin it says :

> Function discoverUnpaired discovers unpaired Bluetooth devices. The success callback is called with a list of objects similar to list, or an empty list if no unpaired devices are found.

And they give some example of list of devices found with their names, classes, mac addresses, etc.

So I kinda hoped that you could help me here are the index.html and index.js of the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Bluetooth transmission</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Bluetooth transmission</h1>

        <button id="button-research" onclick="reshButt()">Research</button>

        <h2>Devices detected:</h2>

        <div id="devices_list">
        </div>

        <p>Click on the device you want to connect to.</p>

        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </center>
</body>
```

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, onError);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('deviceReady');
    bluetoothSerial.enable();
}


//_____BlueTooth_____
function reshButt() {
    alert('deviceReady');
    bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired(
        function(devices) {
            var currentNode;
            devices.forEach(
                function(device){
                    currentNode = document.createElement('div');
                    currentNode.id = device.id;
                    document.getElementById(device.id).innerHTML = '<div id="'+device.name+'" onclick="bluetoothSerial.connect('+device.address+', alert("Connecting to '+device.name+'"), alert("Impossible to connect to '+device.name+'"));">'+device.name+'</div></br>';
           document.getElementById("devices_list").appendChild(currentNode);
                }
            );
        }
     );
  }
  function onError() {
      alert('Error while looking for BlueTooth devices');
  }
```

Sorry for bad indentation, Stack overflow kinda ruined it.
Thank you guys !

Comment: did you find an answer for this problem? i have issue and i'm desperate

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **bluetoothSerial.setDeviceDiscoveredListener** before **bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired**.When discoverUnpaired starts, it calls the device discovered listener if it has been set.

Example:

```
bluetoothSerial.setDeviceDiscoveredListener(function (device) {
                        console.log('Found: ' + device.name); 
});


bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired();
```